# sonata adminBundle entities are not display in the dashboard after admin:generate command line

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I've installed sonata adminbundle and every thing where fine. Now when I want to manage one of the entities (display it in the dashboard) as described in the [official documentation][1], by runing the command line php app/console sonata:admin:generate YourNS/FooBundle/Entity/Bar as describe in the documentation, the command line looks like every thing is fine but the entity is not displayed on the dashboard as it suppose to be and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command only generate the admin classes in the admin directory you need to add those admin classes in your service config file